# RxJava Unit Testing for Observable.Interval, "Context has changed" error

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, junit4, rx-java2

I am trying to write unit tests for the code block below :

```
Observable.interval(INITIAL_DELAY, REFRESH_PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .flatMap {thisMethodReturnsAnObservable()}
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) 
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(this::onDataLoaded, this::onError)
            .disposeLater())
```

I have a test rule that overrides the RxSchedulers with testSchedulers which works.

**Important** the tests can run one by one, but not all together, also run with coverage is broken with the same error.

The error I am getting is, the running of the test immediately stops when debugger hits the `onDataLoaded` method, and displays the following message:
[image: "]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a ComputationSchedulerHandler to my test rule solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `Observable.interval` runs on the the computation scheduler. So you will need to use the overload of `Observable.interval` that takes a scheduler or add `Schedulers.computation` into your test rule.

`Observable.interval(INITIAL_DELAY, REFRESH_PERIOD, TimeUnit.SECONDS, [Your scheduler here])`

[Observable.interval documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#interval-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)